# How do I test methods of classes in which the method is also called in the constructor? (JUnit)

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I am a beginner to Test Driven Development (TDD). Quite often, I have encountered something that does not feel like the proper way to be doing things:

Take, for example, a class with a method called `loadStuff()` which would return `true` or `false` if stuff was loaded or not. This method is called in the constructor of the class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        if (loadStuff())
            System.out.println("Stuff was loaded from constructor");
        else
            System.out.println("Stuff was not loaded from constructor");
    }

    boolean loadStuff() {
        boolean stuffWasLoaded = true;
        //...
        return stuffWasLoaded;
    }
}
```

I would like to test this `loadStuff()` method using `JUnit`. What bothers me is that the method that I am trying to test is being called in the constructor of the class before I can actually test it:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void testLoadStuff() throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();

        assertTrue("Stuff was not loaded from test.", main.loadStuff());
    }
}
```

The test passes, and this is the output:

```
Stuff was loaded from constructor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I feel like I am going about this the wrong way, but am not sure of a better way to do it.

What is the proper way to test a method of a class which is also called within the constructor of that class?

Comment: One option is to write your unit tests to ignore current implementation details, and instead test the externally visible behavior. Write one or more tests for the constructor, and also write one or more tests for the method.

Comment: This is why it's good to have constructors that do nothing more than initialize variables. Could you make `loadStuff()` public? If not, reflection could. Is the purpose of `loadStuff()` to initialize variables for `Main`? What exactly are you testing?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I am testing a case in which I have a certain Manager which parses an XML file into an array for use by other classes. When the Manager is instantiated, it immediately begins the process of loading, parsing, etc. the XML file. I want to test the methods that load and parse the file to make sure they give the expected output, but to do so I have to call the constructor, which does that all anyway. I can call the methods from the instantiator, that's no problem, I just found it simpler to put them all in the constructor, since they would be called right after anyway.

Comment: I suggest separating `load` and `parse`, then exposing these methods so they can be of use to the client of the object. You could expose a `loadAndParse` method if you wanted it to happen simuataniously (kinda like some network APIs use `writeAndFlush`). If you want the data to be loaded and parsed before using the object (which is why it's in the constructor), throw an exception if there was a problem, then test for the exception.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Okay, I will do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this completely new code? as if so using TDD your situation as described should not arise.

The cycle is:

1. Write a failing (but compiling test)
2. Write the minimum amount of code to pass the test
3. Refactor (tidy up and remove duplication)

Following this, its not possible to have an untested method call in the constructor.

You want to test behaviour of your class, not the individual methods as such. Decide what behaviour you want, write a test case that tests the expected output, then write the code.

Comment: Yes, this is new code. I attempted to follow that cycle, however I guess I must not have followed it correctly. Thank you for your input, I will re-evaluate the steps I have taken. :)